# How can I get a Play of the Game with Mercy?

Tags: overwatch

I remember Mercy getting Play of the Games back when you could revive multiple team members with the ultimate ability. This is not longer possible, since you can only revive a single team mate.

All I can think of is killing multiple enemies with the Caduceus Blaster in quick succession. This is an extremely unlikely event.

Is there another, more realistic, way?

Answer (score 9):

The Play of the Game system is mostly based on how much of the On Fire bar you accumulate. So in general your best best is to do (or boost) a lot of damage or a lot of healing within 10 seconds, and hope that no one else on the team has something better. The game also prioritizes actions done later in the game (especially overtime). I believe Mercy also gets extra fire if the person she resurrects does good immediately after, but I'm not sure.

However, there are a few other ways to get PotG that occasionally pop up, and are noted by their special subtitle.

- "Sharpshooter" PotGs are when the system decides the distance and movement between you and the people you kill are impressive.
- "Livesaver" PotGs are when you kill an enemy who has just stunned or frozen an ally.
- "Shutdown" PotGs are for killing enemies using ultimates.

For Mercy specifically, one not-all-that-unlikely idea is to kill a McCree, Brigitte, or Mei who's just incapacitated someone, and then heal them as much as you can afterward. Mei is probably the safest to try - keep healing the person being frozen to ensure they can survive the followup icicle, shoot the Mei, and continue healing afterward.

Comment: I can pretty much confirm this answer. Since the "Mercy PotG nerf" I've only seen/had very few and on every single one was at least one blaster kill. Usually it goes somewhat like this: res someone (who then does a lot of damage/kills), get 1-2 kills yourself and do a lot of healing on the entire team (in overtime).

Answer (score 0):

I got my POTG with mercy for reviving an ally (reaper),and he used his ult and got a two full kills. 
So that's another way!

Answer (score -2):

Doing damage with Mercy can be very difficult, especially with her little pistol but, being near an enemy while healing a teammate can inflict damage on them. Try that and see how it goes. Or use the pistol.